# When I manually write to the .toc file, what should be the fourth argument of \contentsline?

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, package-writing

I want to change my table of contents manually. The reason is that my document isn't so much made out of "sections", but rather "exercises". I have written a customized command to do this and it almoast works. The following commands are put in a custom `.sty` file, loaded after `hyperref`:

```
\def\numberline@exer#1{%
\makebox[50pt][l]{\bf Ex. #1\hspace*{1em}}
}

\def\exercise#1{%
\section*{#1}\refstepcounter{exercise}\phantomsection%
\write\@auxout{%
    \protect\@writefile{toc}{%
        \protect\contentsline {section}{\numberline@exer{\theexercise}Title}{\thepage}%
{????}% This is the fourth argument, defined by hyperref
        }%
    }%
}
```

This basically does exactly what I want, exept it doesn't create a bookmark. This is probably due to the fourth argument.  I tried to find how `hyperref` redefines `\contentsline`, but I find `hyperref.sty` impossible to understand.

So my question is: What should the fourth argument in my definition be? I would also like to know how this fourth argument works, but this is low priority.

N.B. I am not interested in installing any packages that can customize ToCs. I am doing this as practice, so I would very much like to use my own `.sty` file for this.

Comment: Wouldn't it be much much much more simpler to define a new float (even if it is non-floating) and have stuff done by a package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Normally, any changes of `\contentsline` etc. should be done before `hyperref` is loaded, afterwards one has to consider the `4th` argument of `\contentsline`, being added by `hyperref`.

The `4th` argument is the hyperanchor, i.e. something like `section.1` or `east.17`.

The hyperanchor can be inserted with `\@currentHref`, which should provide the correct anchor since `\phantomsection` has been used.

In order to add the bookmark, use `\Hy@writebookmark`, since `\contentsline` itself does not add the bookmarks, that's done in the wrapper command `\addcontentsline`, which is 'by-passed' here.

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref}


\newcounter{exercise}


\makeatletter

\def\numberline@exer#1{%
\makebox[50pt][l]{\bfseries Ex. #1\hspace*{1em}}
}

\def\exercise#1{%
  \phantomsection
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \section*{#1}%
  \Hy@writebookmark{\csname theexercise\endcsname}{#1}{\@currentHref}{\toclevel@section}{toc}
  \write\@auxout{%
    \protect\@writefile{toc}{%
      \protect\contentsline {section}{\numberline@exer{\theexercise}#1}{\thepage}{\@currentHref}%
    }%
  }%

}
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}\label{foosection}

\clearpage

\blindtext[3]
\exercise{Foo}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

[image]

**Update** A version with usual `\addcontentsline`:

```
\documentclass{article}


\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref}


\newcounter{exercise}


\makeatletter

\newcommand*\l@exercise[2]{%
  \ifnum \c@tocdepth >\z@
    \addpenalty\@secpenalty
    \addvspace{1.0em \@plus\p@}%
    \setlength\@tempdima{3.8em}%
    \begingroup
      \parindent \z@ \rightskip \@pnumwidth
      \parfillskip -\@pnumwidth
      \leavevmode \bfseries
      \advance\leftskip\@tempdima
      \hskip -\leftskip
      #1\nobreak\hfil \nobreak\hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hss #2}\par
    \endgroup
  \fi}



\let\toclevel@exercise\toclevel@section

\newcommand{\exercisebetter}[1]{%
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \section*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{exercise}{\protect\numberline{Ex: \theexercise}#1}
}


\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}\label{foosection}

\clearpage

\blindtext[3]

\exercisebetter{Foobar}
\blindtext[2]


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please note that this is a quick and dirty example only... a better MWE would show more content and it is advisable to check whether `hyperref` is loaded or not

Comment: I've put `\HyperGlobalCurrentHref` in the fourth argument. I still don't get bookmarks in Adobe. Also, if I click on the ToC enty the document is jumped to just below the title of the section, not showing the section title (though I believe this is a `\phantomsection` problem??)

Comment: The `\phantomsection` will not provide with a bookmark, nor will `\contentsline` do.

Comment: I should think of something else for that then. I should also note that loading my custom `.sty` before hyperref doesn't seem to change anything. Nor does writing the `\def..` in the preamble before hyperref.

Comment: But on the whole your answer is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: @gebruiker: I am working on a solution for the bookmark etc.

Comment: @gebruiker: See the update please

Comment: Why not using `\addcontentsline{exercise}{\protect\ext@numberline{\theexercise}{#1}` and defining `\l@exercise`? If you also define `\toclevel@exercise` `hyperref` will do bookmarking automatically. And `\addcontentsline` automatically respects `\nofile`, something missing in the solution above.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: Don't ask me, ask the O.P.  ;-) If the  OP request it this way it is his/her decision

Comment: @Schweinebacke: To calm you down: I added the 'traditional' way as well ;-)

Comment: You can make it simpler, I'll add a suggestion as answer because it's to large for a comment.

Comment: @Schweinebacke and Christian Hupfer, thank you for both your inputs. As I said, I'm doing this to practice, so the different points of view you gave me are really appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend not to use `\write\@auxout` directly but use `\addcontentsline`. `\addcontentsline` automatically respects `\nofile` and uses `\protected@write` so you can use `\protect` to protect fragile commands. And `hyperref` automatically handles bookmarks etc. if you use `\addcontentsline`. So you don't need to know how to set the 4th argument of `\contents` added by `hyperref`. A very simple solution that does work independent from using `hyperref` or not (and independent whether `hyperref` is loaded before or after the additional code) would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bookmarksopen]{hyperref}

\providecommand*{\texorpdfstring}[2]{#1}% Needed if `hyperref` is not used.
\newcounter{exercise}
\makeatletter
\def\numberline@exer#1{%
  \texorpdfstring{\makebox[50pt][l]{\bfseries Ex. #1\hspace*{1em}}}{Ex. #1}
}

\newcommand\l@exercise{\l@section}
\newcommand*{\exercise}{%
  \@dblarg\@exercise
}
\newcommand*{\@exercise}[2][]{%
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \section*{#2}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{exercise}{\protect\numberline@exer{\theexercise}#1}%
}
\let\toclevel@exercise\toclevel@section
\makeatother

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{First section}\label{foosection}

\clearpage

\blindtext[3]
\exercise{Foo}
\blindtext[2]
\exercise[Bar]{Foo-Bar}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

With this solution `\exercise` like `\section` also has an optional argument to set and different text for the table of contents. See `\exercise[Bar]{Foo-Bar}` in the example.